# Using JQuery's ajax to scrape webpage

Tags: jquery

I simply need to get the 'html' from a particular (cross domain) request.

I'm using the JQuery.ajax() function passing `dataType=json` so that JQuery generates a `script` tag and fires off the request.
Here's the code:

> ```
>             var url="http://www.google.com/callback=?";
>             $.ajax({
>                 type: 'GET',
>                 url: url,
>                 dataType: 'json',
>                 success: function(data) {$("#out").append("success "+data); },
>                 error: function(data) {$("#out").append("failure "+data); },
>                 complete: function(data) {$("#out").append("complete "+data); },
>                 data: {},
>                 async: false
>             });
> ```

Now, the odd bit is that, using firebug, I do see the generated script tag AND the response from the remote server, but none of my callbacks are being called.
[image: Jquery's script tag injection for cross domain calls]

How do I get the html returned from the `ajax()` call? Am I using the wrong function in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback isn't called because the document returned is not a JavaScript application consisting of a function call to that callback.

JSON-P works by running third party JS that calls a function on your page.

You [can't use client side code to get content that isn't expressed as JavaScript from a different origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

If you want to get such content then you need to proxy it through a server. Either one on the same origin (so you can get the content directly) or one that [transforms it to JSON-P](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Comment: Thanks Qeuntin. If you read between the lines, I am trying to get out of the same origin policy, without the need for a proxy. The jsonp hack is so that the browser sends the request, I know the browser receives the output too, but I just cant get a handle to it. I'm ok if the call backs dont execute (async=false should help here)

Comment: The browser won't let you get a handle on it, that is the point of the same origin policy.

Comment: well, it sure likes firebug more than it likes me :)

Comment: Firebug is a browser extension, it isn't (and doesn't need to be) subject to the same restrictions as code provided by a webpage the user happened to visit.